# Running php bin/magento setup:upgrade stuck

Tags: magento2, installation, setup-upgrade, aws

[image]

I am running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
command after migration from one aws instance to another Instance and It is hanged and stuck  not moving forward??

Comment: I would suggest to check the log files and also check the directory var, pub and generation permission.

Comment: It runs but take a lot of time

Comment: did you check log file?

Comment: No I am checking

Answer (score 5):

please enable verbose mode or run command with strace

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade -vvv
```

> and tail magento logs to see whats going on,

```
strace -s 99999 bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> see at the end whats going on

Comment: -bash : strace : command not found

Comment: you can install `strace` package :)

Comment: thanks i can see what is going on my magento install, before it just hung on setup:install

Answer (score 2):

> You can check by run below command:

```
strace -s 99 bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

More about [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace#:%7E:text=strace%20is%20a%20diagnostic%2C%20debugging,and%20changes%20of%20process%20state.)

Also, check your MySQL has not run any related process, you found then kill it. (Not KILL ALL, only related Processes need to kill)

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST

kill ProcessID
```

In My case customer_visitor table cause an error and stops the command. After debugging more in DB, there are many entries, so he takes more time to run and stop the upgrade command execution.

I remove all entries from *customer_visitor* table and then It's working.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE customer_visitor;
```

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to check stale cron:run processes before deployment (setup:upgrade)
If you find it then kill it and clean them in cron_schedule table as well